# Gale-Shapley algorithm with multiple partners for each side

Tags: game-theory, algorithms, matching

Suppose I have a bipartite graph with males on one side and females on the other.

The usually discussed Gale-Shapley algorithm matches each male to a female, and ends up with a stable matching.

What if we allow for multiple partners of the same individual, for both sides? Say, 2 females per male and also 2 males per female, with no other restriction? Basically we assign to each individual, a set of 2 individuals from the other side of the graph.

This isn't too radical a generalisation, so I guess there must be some literature on this. Any resources to study that?

Comment: I think what you are describing are either "one-to-many" or "many-to-many" matchings. There is indeed considerable literature, one good reference is Echenique, F., & Oviedo, J. (2004). A theory of stability in many-to-many matching markets. They offer a generalization of GS called T-algorithm. Also, I think, it would be helpful to clarify what the preferences are in your case - can partners be complementary? The difficulty of the problem depends on that, and the stable matching may not exist without substitutability.